# Using predicate logic to solve text questions for 10-years-old?

Tags: logic, education

I am going through a exam preparation book with a 10-years-old. I thought that predicate logic would make it easier to solve questions like the one below. My hope was to use [Rules of Inference](https://cse.iitk.ac.in/users/cs365/2012/rulesLogic.html), but I struggle with it. I have not studied predicate logic explicitly and specifically have not studied  translating English expressions.
I am using the definitions of [RFC2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) for MUST,SHOULD, etc. to help my understanding of the question.

With this background, my question is: Is there an easy way to translate the question below and prove that an answer is possible/impossible to construct with the given statements?

"

1. If Emily does not have work, she is likely to have no money.
2. If she has no money, she cannot afford her favourite car and will buy a cheaper car.
3. If Emily has her favourite car, she will definitely drive to York."

If the above statements are correct, which one of the following could be true?

**A)** If Emily has work, she will definitely drive to York.

**B)** If Emily drove to York, she definitely has money.

**C)** If Emily does not have money, she might drive to York.

**D)** If Emily does not have work, she will definitely not drive to York.

The **correct answer** is given as **B)** in the preparation book.

---

My translation of the statements:

$1.) \neg Job => \neg Money$

$2.) \neg Money => \neg GoodCar$

$3.) GoodCar => GoToYork$

My translation of the answers:

$A.) Job => GoToYork$

$B.) GoToYork => Money$

$C.) \neg Money => GoToYork$

$D.) \neg Job => \neg GoToYork$

---

My idea was to list all expressions that we can generate through Modus Tollens (M.T.), which I understand as $ (p=>q) => ( \neg q => \neg p )$

$MT1.) Money => Job$

$MT2.) GoodCar => Money$

$MT3.) \neg GoToYork => \neg GoodCar $

Now we have 6 statements to check our answers against and I seem to come up with 'not enough information given' for all of the answers. Especially that there is no condition given under which a favourite car would be bought.

Comment: None of the given choices are necessarily true.  The implication that "if Emily has her favorite car then she will drive to York" does not mean that she can not drive to York in a cheaper car.

Comment: Suggestion: To avoid confusion, stick to "real-world" logical propositions in the present tense. Define "$P$ implies $Q$" to mean that it is not the case that both $P$ is true and $Q$ is false (present tense).  Example: "It is raining implies it is cloudy" means only that, at present, it is not both raining and not cloudy. Stress that "$P$ implies $Q$" does not mean that $P$ causes $Q$. Avoid predicate logic until students have mastered propositional logic.

Comment: The above "definition" of implication can be formally proven from what might be called "first principles," but this would require some knowledge of the formal methods of proof.

Comment: For one, you're using propositional logic... not predicate logic. Secondly, the question doesn't ask which answer choice *must* be true; rather, it asks which answer choice *could* be true. For this reason, inference rules such as "Modus Tollens" won't necessarily help you find the correct answer. Inference rules deduce statements that *must* be true, but you must identify statements that have a *possibility* of being true. Easiest way: contruct a truth table including all statements involved, and then look for a row in which $1,2,3$ are true and at least one of the answer choices is true.